# Optimality of teleportation for entanglement-assisted quantum channel coding

Tags: information-theory, teleportation, communication, channel-capacity

**Setting:**

Consider a quantum channel $N_{A\rightarrow B}$ between Alice and Bob. Let Alice and Bob also share arbitrary amounts of entanglement assistance through the state $\phi_{A_EB_E}$ (these can be many copies of maximally entangled states or more generally, whatever state Alice and Bob want). We will examine channel coding in the one-shot regime.

The goal is to transfer the $A'$ register of some pure quantum state $\psi_{RA'}$ through this channel. Here $R$ is an inaccessible purifying register. Let there be an encoder $E_{A_EA'\rightarrow A}$ and decoder $D_{B_EB\rightarrow B'}$. Let

$$(I_{R}\otimes D\circ N\circ E)(\psi_{RA'} \otimes \phi_{A_EB_E}) = \rho_{RB'}$$

Our criterion for success is $\inf_{\psi_{RA'}}F(\rho_{RB'}, \psi_{RA'})$ where we optimize over all encoder decoder pairs and then find the "worst-case" state $\psi_{RA'}$.

---

**One possible protocol:**

One way to transmit a quantum state given arbitrary entanglement assistance is through teleportation. Hence, Alice and Bob should try and teleport the state $\psi_{RA'}$ and only use the channel to send the classical information that is part of the teleportation protocol. If the worst-case error caused by the channel in transmitting $2|A'|$ bits of classical information is $\varepsilon$, then we can apply the teleportation protocol for $\psi_{RA'}$ and the teleported state is
$$(1-\varepsilon)\vert\psi_{RA'}\rangle\langle\psi_{RA'}\vert + \varepsilon\vert\psi_{RA'}^\perp\rangle\langle\psi_{RA'}^\perp\vert$$

The worst case fidelity is then $\sqrt{1-\varepsilon}$.

---

**Question:**

Is this teleportation-based protocol optimal and if yes, why? Or is there a better encoder decoder pair that could achieve a better fidelity given the assumption that using entanglement assistance and the channel, one can transmit at most $2|A'|$ bits with error $\varepsilon$?